# Ubuntu VPN Gateway Conf: IPtables Rules & ProxyARP

Tags: vpn, routing, gateway, vpn-client, wireguard

I want to use an ubuntu 18.04 box (at 192.168.1.50) running a WireGuard client for a commercial VPN as gateway to the LAN. WG is using wg-quick and enabled as a service. Unbound is installed and systemd-resolved is set to DNSStubListener=no. resolv.conf is set to use the same DNS server designated by the VPN provider (per wg0.conf).

The main router is at 192.168.1.1 and blocks external access to the VPN gateway (I know INPUT is open).

The gateway is working, but the IPtables rules need work. **How to tighten the rules when the goal is only to allow the box to work as a gateway?** I want to use IPtables only for the config necessary to make this work, all else should go in UFW, which is not yet installed. These IPtables rules will be placed in wg0.conf's PostUp/PostDown.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere             udp dpt:domain
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**UPDATE:** Although the config above works, I've flushed iptables to start anew.